# AtTask API search all objCode by multiple ids

Tags: attask

Thanks in advance for reading this and any help you can provide.

I'm trying to use the AtTask API to return a listing of multiple objects by their IDs. The issue I am running into is the objects all have a different objCode. I can do a search for each type via /issue?id=123,456 or /task?id=654,321 but I would rather have one call that searches by all IDs. So far I have tried /search?objCode=ALL&query=123,456 and that returns a 'does not support textual search operation. I'm not sure if this is even possible and I guess I can live with writing 3 separate search api calls by objCode but didn't think that would be very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, the objCode is a central, required component of the API, so three calls will be necessary